# Take ID from one table and return related name from another table

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have two tables outlined below:

```
Transactions
ID | Buyer | Seller
-------------------
 1 |   1   |   2
 2 |   1   |   3
 3 |   2   |   3

ClientData
ID | Name
---------
 1 | John
 2 | Terry
 3 | Bob
```

I want to be able to run a query that will return the transaction ID and the client names instead of the buyer and seller ID. I know that JOIN will be used for this, but all the examples I've run across only seem to work with a single related ID, where this needs to do it twice in the query. Is a JOIN the correct way to do this, or should I look into perhaps a sub-query inside the query?

```
SELECT Transactions.ID, Transactions.Buyer, Transactions.Seller 
FROM Transactions 
INNER JOIN ClientData ON Transactions.Buyer=ClientData.ID
AND Transaction.Seller=ClientData.ID
```

This query doesn't return any data, and if I remote the

```
AND Transaction.Seller=ClientData.ID
```

from the query it just returns the raw Transactions data. Previously I would just read the raw transactions data into an array, then I would loop back through the array and replace the buyer and seller ID with the client name manually, but that is incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT t.ID, b.Name, s.Name 
FROM Transactions t
INNER JOIN ClientData b ON t.Buyer=b.ID
INNER JOIN ClientData s ON t.Seller=s.ID
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking, but couldn't put into code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use 2 joins, one for the buyer and one to the seller, like this:

```
SELECT Transactions.ID, BUYER.NAME, SELLER.NAME
FROM transactions T
JOIN Clientdata BUYER
ON T.BUYER=BUYER.ID
JOIN Clientdata SELLER
ON T.SELLER=SELLER.ID
```